# Access spring model object from jsp custom tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am trying to access my model object of spring mvc which is assigned like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMethod(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("attrib", attribute);
}
```

I am trying to access the attribute object in my custom tag lib here is the code.

```
    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException {
        final JspWriter writer = getJspContext().getOut();
        try {
            attribute = (Attribute)
                    getJspContext().getAttribute("attrib");
            if (attribute != null) {
                System.out.print(attribute.getId());
            }
            writer.println("sandeep");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But attribute is always coming as null, can anyone tell me how to access attribute object from my custom taglib

Answer (score 0):

Try to use evaluate method from ExpressionEvaluationUtils as shown below:

```
ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluate("", "attrib", this.pageContext);
```

Refer JavaDoc here : http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils.html